# K-folds do we still need to implement train_test_split?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split, k-fold

I've been reading quite a bit and i'm a little confused with k-folds. I understand the concept behind it, but i'm not sure about how to deploy it.

The usual step that i've been seeing after data exploration is `train_test_split`, encoding and scaling `fit_transform` the training sets and just fitting the testing sets before testing which algorithms work. After which they tune the hyper-parameters.

So if I were to use k-folds now, do I avoid using train_test_split? And at which do we use k-folds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. K-fold splits your data into train-test split `K` times so you train `K` different models.

This approach makes your model results more robust because you train `K` different models with different parts of your dataset and also you predict different parts of your data `K` times. Finally, you can simply take the average score of `K` model.

Comment: hi Batuhan, so right after data explodation, we can implement k-folds am i right?

Comment: Yes you can. Also don't forget to make normalization on your dataset before splitting.